# Xgboost GPU predict keeps crashing Jupyter notebook Python kernel

Tags: python-3.x, windows-10, jupyter-notebook, gpu, xgboost

I have trained an xgboost model using the GPU and I have saved the model. However, when I start a new session and load the model, when I try to predict on new data, the kernel crashes, every time. There is a similar question here ([Xgboost (GPU) crashing while predicting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51737614/xgboost-gpu-crashing-while-predicting)), however I do not have an active booster to delete. I have checked my GPU memory and it is currently at 0.

I am using Windows 10, Jupyter Notebook Python 3.

Comment: What happens when you use a simple decision tree? Just curious, because I am pretty sure pandas has problem with memory utilization.