# How do I free all memory on GPU in XGBoost?

Tags: python, gpu, xgboost

Here is my code:

```
clf = xgb.XGBClassifier(
  tree_method = 'gpu_hist',
  gpu_id = 0,
  n_gpus = 4,
  random_state = 55,
  n_jobs = -1
)
clf.set_params(**params)
clf.fit(X_train, y_train, **fit_params)
```

I've read the answers on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51737614/xgboost-gpu-crashing-while-predicting) and this [git issue](https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/issues/3045) but neither worked.

I tried to delete the booster in this way:

```
clf._Booster.__del__()
gc.collect()
```

It deletes the booster but doesn't completely free up GPU memory.

I guess it's `Dmatrix` that is still there but I am not sure.

How can I free the whole memory?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, I don't think there is a way that you can have access to the loaded Dmatrix cause the `fit` function doesn't return it.
you can check the source code [here on this github link](https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/blob/master/python-package/xgboost/sklearn.py):

So I think the best way is to wrap it in a Process and run it that way, like this:

```
from multiprocessing import Process

def fitting(args):
    clf = xgb.XGBClassifier(tree_method = 'gpu_hist',gpu_id = 0,n_gpus = 4, random_state = 55,n_jobs = -1)
    clf.set_params(**params)
    clf.fit(X_train, y_train, **fit_params)

    #save the model here on the disk

fitting_process = Process(target=fitting, args=(args))
fitting process.start()
fitting_process.join()

# load the model from the disk here
```